# Understanding ELK Analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

Am newby to ELK 5.1.1 stack and I have a few questions just for my understanding.
I have setup this stack basicaly with standard analyzers / filters and everything works great.
My data source is a MySQL backend that I index using Logstash.
I would like to deal with queries containing accents and hopefully `asciifolding` token filter can help achieve this.

First I learned out how to create custom analyzer and save as template.
Right now when I query this url `http://localhost:9200/_template?pretty` I have 2 templates: the logstash default template named `logstash` and my custom template which settings are:

```
"custom_template" : {
    "order" : 1,
    "template" : "doo*",
    "settings" : {
        "index" : {
            "analysis" : {
                "analyzer" : {
                    "myCustomAnalyzer" : {
                        "filter" : [
                            "standard",
                            "lowercase",
                            "asciifolding"
                        ],
                        "tokenizer" : "standard"
                   }
               }
         },
        "refresh_interval" : "5s"
     }
    },
    "mappings" : { },
    "aliases" : { }
}
```

Searching for the keyword `Yaoundé` returns 70 hits but when I search for `Yaounde` I keep having no hit. 
Below is my query for the second case

```
{
"query": {
    "query_string": {
        "query": "yaounde",
        "fields": [
            "title"
        ]
    }
},
"from": 0,
"size": 10
}
```

Please can somebody help me guess what am doing wrong here?
Also knowing that my data is analyzed by Logstash during the index process do I really have to specify that the analyzer `myCustomAnalyzer` should be applied during the research as per this second query ?

```
{
     "query": {
    "query_string": {
        "query": "yaounde",
        "fields": [
            "title"
        ],
        "analyzer": "myCustomAnalyzer"
    }
},
"from": 0,
"size": 10
}
```

Here is a sample of the output part of my logstash config file

```
output {
stdout { codec => json_lines }
if [type] == "announces" {
    elasticsearch {  
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
        document_id => "%{job_id}"
        index => "dooone"
    document_type => "%{type}"
    }
} else {
    elasticsearch {  
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
    document_id => "%{uid}"
    index => "dootwo"
    document_type => "%{type}"
    }
}
}
```

Thank You

Comment: Did you add a mapping to the field title? Not really clear from you code sample.

Comment: The mapping of my fields right now are automatically set by Logstash during the indexing process. Does this answer to your question @JettroCoenradie ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good place to start is with the index template documentation of elasticsearch:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html

An example for your scenario that could work for the title field:

```
"custom_template" : {
    "order" : 1,
    "template" : "doo*",
    "settings" : {
        "index" : {
            "analysis" : {
                "analyzer" : {
                    "myCustomAnalyzer" : {
                        "filter" : [
                            "standard",
                            "lowercase",
                            "asciifolding"
                        ],
                        "tokenizer" : "standard"
                   }
               }
         },
        "refresh_interval" : "5s"
     }
    },
    "mappings" : {
      "your_type": {
        "properties": {
          "title": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "myCustomAnalyzer"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "aliases" : { }
}
```

An alternative would be to change the dynamic mapping. You can find a good example right here for strings.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html#match-mapping-type

Comment: Thank you. it worked!
I used your solution to define a mapping for my title field and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the mapping of your document ?

(GET /my_index/my_doc/_mapping )

The analyser you provide as argument in your query does only apply at search time, not at indexation time. So if you haven't set this analyser in your mapping, the string is still indexed with "default" analyzer, so it will not match your results.

The analyzer you provide at search time will apply on your query string, but then it will look into indexed data, which is indexed as "Yaoundé", not "yaounde".

Comment: Right now if I query this url http://localhost:9200/dooone/announces/_mapping?pretty It shows something like this image [![this image][1]][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/02Ojn.png

Comment: If I rather query `http://localhost:8270/dooone/_settings?pretty` it shows the correct settings that I have setup as my template before indexation by logstash

Comment: Can you provide your template ?

Comment: I had to use define the analyzer to be use in the mapping section `"mapping" : {... }`
My problem is definitively solved. Thanks for your assistance.